# Wordpress add custom taxonomy to custom menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have searched and searched and can't find another way other than what I will refer to as the 'hack method' to add a custom taxonomy to a custom admin menu.

```
add_menu_page(
        'Practice Directory',
        'Practice Directory',
        'read',
        'practice-directory',
        '',
        'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
        40
);
```

Then I register my post types and make sure they use

```
'show_in_menu'          => 'practice-directory',
```

This works and the custom post types show in my custom menu.

But a custom taxonomy doesn't accept a string for the same property only true or false.

```
    'show_in_menu'          => 'false',
```

So to add it you have to create a submenu page

```
add_submenu_page(
    'practice-directory',
    'Doctors',
    'Doctors',
    'edit_posts',
    'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=doctor',
    false
);
```

Which is a 'hacked' way of doing it.

Is there another way? **Without modifying the WordPress core** could I overwrite register_taxonomy function to be able to accept a string for 'show_in_menu' and follow the functionality of the register_post_type?

requested screenshot

[image]

Comment: could you please show me some screenshot of your needs?

Comment: @developerme not sure how to get you a screenshot of what I am looking for. If you understand what add_menu_page does and then the show_in_menu property of a custom post type does you would know that I am adding a menu item to the admin menu of WordPress. Then to add a custom taxonomy to that same menu it can't be done with the same property that is available when registering a custom taxonomy because it only accepts true or false, and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found is to create a submenu like you did, and set the menu active when we are on taxonomy page:

create your admin menu:

```
add_menu_page('Page title', 'Menu title', 'read', 'menu_slug', false, 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus', 25);
```

add custom post type if needed:

```
register_post_type('your_cpt_name', array(
    ...
    'show_in_menu' =>  'menu_slug',//your previously created menu slug
    ...
));
```

add your custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('your_taxonomy_name', 'your_cpt_name', $args);
```

add your taxo submenu:

```
add_submenu_page('menu_slug', 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'custom_post_capability', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_taxonomy_name&post_type=your_cpt_name', false);
```

add filter for menu highlighting when active:

```
add_filter('parent_file', 'highlightTaxoSubMenu');

function highlightTaxoSubMenu($parent_file){
    global $submenu_file, $current_screen, $pagenow;
    if ($current_screen->post_type == 'your_cpt_name') {
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' && $current_screen->taxonomy == 'your_taxonomy_name' ) {
            $submenu_file = 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_taxonomy_name&post_type=your_cpt_name';
        }
        $parent_file = 'menu_slug';//your parent menu slug
    }
    return $parent_file;
}
```

Edit:
When your CPT is placed as submenu in administration, custom user Roles can't create new post for this CPT if they don't have 'edit_posts' capability ( even if they have your cpt edit capability ).
A workaround is to add a 'create new post' link for this custom post in your submenu

```
add_submenu_page('menu_slug', 'Add', 'Add', 'custom_post_capability', 'post-new.php?post_type=your_cpt_name', false);
```